# Suppressing the virtuality of a C++ function in a class hierarchy

Tags: c++

This is purely a theoretical question.  I don't have a particular use case in mind.

Can the virtuality of a C++ function be suppressed somewhere down the class hierarchy, or is it that once a virtual function is defined in a base class, it remains virtual down the rest of its class hierarchy?

I wrote some sample code where I was attempting to suppress the virtuality of a method defined up the class hierarchy but I did not succeed.  My sample code follows:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void myFunc() {
    std::cout << "myFunc in Base" << std::endl;
  }
};
 
class Child : public Base {
public:
  void myFunc() {
  std::cout << "myFunc in Child" << std::endl;
  }
};
 
class GrandChild : public Child {
public:
  void myFunc() {
  std::cout << "myFunc in GrandChild" << std::endl;
  }
};



int main() {
  Base* ptr = new GrandChild();
  ptr->myFunc();
  return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
myFunc in GrandChild
```

Comment: There is no going back once you use `virtual`

Comment: No. (This space intentionally left blank)

Comment: No - similarly to that you cannot remove a member variable, as then the is-a relationship wouldn't be fulfilled - but what is the problem you're trying to solve (even if it's theoretical)?

Comment: possibly an XY problem? why would you want to suppress it when the only real reason for using inheritance is virtual function dispatch?

Comment: Loosely related: you can have a template base that specifies whether you want a function to be virtual.

Comment: What does it mean to "suppress virtuality"? If you could somehow change a method from virtual to non-virtual in a derived class, then a base class pointer to a derived class object would still do a vtable lookup to discover that the virtual method has been made non-virtual, which seems like a contradiction.

Comment: What [output](https://godbolt.org/z/j6PP4a1za) did you want?

Comment: Read about the [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) keyword.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is create a member with a different signature (even using defaulted arguments).

That is:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::foo" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct Derived : Base
{
    void foo(int = 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::foo" << std::endl;
    }
};
...
Base * ptr = new Derived;
ptr->foo(); // will invoke Base::foo()
```

Comment: Wait, this does not create an ambiguity? An interesting case of shadowing here.